# rijndael-128 cbc javascript does not return correct like php mcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

In php i use mcrypt to encrypt my string with key and lv...now i im porting my php code project to node js and need to get same encrypted string in javascript like in php... my data is the following:

```
lv:       968kjnv0myizvjio
key:      9qdx524o5rzytekr
string:   androidtest
encoding: rijndael-128
mode:     cbc
```

In php i get this correct encrypted string:
9620825aa10ce13d9e886b6dec146074

In javascript(node library) i get this:
6c6943435771454d34543265694774743742526764413d3d

My code is this:

```
var MCrypt = require('mcrypt').MCrypt;

var desEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'cbc');
desEcb.open('9qdx524o5rzytekr', '968kjnv0myizvjio'); // we are set the key and lv

var ciphertext = desEcb.encrypt('androidtest');
console.log(bin2hex(ciphertext.toString('base64')));

function bin2hex(s) {
    var i
    var l
    var o = ''
    var n
    s += ''
    for (i = 0, l = s.length; i < l; i++) {
        n = s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)
        o += n.length < 2 ? '0' + n : n
    }
    return o
}
```

I im using this library:

```
https://github.com/tugrul/node-mcrypt
```

How can i get same result in node js (javascript) like in PHP posted above?
Or do you know another library that works in node js to get same result as PHP?
Or maybe write custom function to get this above archived?

Comment: have you noticed that the javascript result, each hex-digit pair is within the printable ascii range, and the last two pairs are ascii `==` ... looks like a base64 string converted to hex ... if you decode that base64 ... guess what you get :p

Comment: so, this should tell you why `ciphertext.toString('base64')` is not the right thing to do

Comment: i im new to this decoding stuff...in php i get correct values so my android device decode it success...so i need to remove base64?

Comment: well ... yes ... do you convert to base64 in PHP before you convert to HEX? - remove `.toString('base64')` - see what the result is

Comment: Yes you are right...i remove it and i get <Buffer 96 20 82 5a a1 0c e1 3d 9e 88 6b 6d ec 14 60 74>

Comment: Thank you..i spend two days figuring out why string is not correct...thanks :) But how to convert this buffer to string so that i can use it as string...if i convert buffer to string without base64 i get strange result

Comment: the `3d3d` at the end pointed to base64 (it's `==` - typical bas64) (didn't even read your code, just the outputs at that stage) ... converting from base64 to hex I could see the result was identical

Comment: `console.log(ciphertext.toString('hex'));` .. perhaps (you don't need your `bin2hex` function at all

Comment: Thanks that fixes the problem and now my buffer is in hex format encoded..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't convert the ciphertext to base64 - you don't in PHP, so that's one point of different

You don't need your `bin2hex` function, because node can do it for you

```
var ciphertext = desEcb.encrypt('androidtest');
console.log(ciphertext.toString('hex')); //9620825aa10ce13d9e886b6dec146074
```